# Target not known beforehand in the Makefile

Tags: makefile, build

I am trying to use makefile to manage my building process in a small project, where the target number and target names are not known beforehand but depends on the input. Specifically, I want to generate a bunch of data files (say `.csv` files) according to a `cities_list.txt` file with a list of city names inside. For example, if the contents of the txt file are:

> newyork
>   washington
>   toronto

then a script called `write_data.py` would generate three files called `newyork.csv`, `washington.csv` and `toronto.csv`. When the content of the `cities_list.txt` file changes, I want make to deal with this change cleverly, i.e. only update the new-added cities files.

I was trying to define variable names in target names to make this happen but didn't succeed. I'm now trying to create a bunch of intermediate `.name` files as below:

```
all: *.csv

%.name: cities_list.txt
        /bin/bash gen_city_files.sh $<

%.csv: %.name write_data.py
        python3 write_data.py $<

clean:
        rm *.name *.csv
```

This seems to be very close to success, but it only gives me one .csv file. The reason is obvious, because make can't determine what files should be generated for the `all` target. How can I let make know that this `*.csv` should contain all the files where there exists a corresponding `*.name` file? Or is there any better way to achieve what I wanted to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All right, *this* should do it. We'd like a variable assignment at the head of the file:

```
CITY_FILES := newyork.csv washington.csv toronto.csv
```

There are **two** ways to do this. This way:

```
-include cities.mak

# this rule can come later in the makefile, near the bottom
cities.mak: cities_list.txt
    @sed 's/^/CITIES := /' $< > $@
```

and this way:

```
CITIES := $(shell cat cities_list.txt)
```

After we've done one of those two, we can construct the list of needed files:

```
CITY_FILES := $(addsuffix .csv, $(CITIES))
```

and build them:

```
# It is convenient to have this be the first rule in the makefile.
all: $(CITY_FILES)

%.csv: write_data.py
    python3 $< $*.name
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Did you miss the dependence of `%.csv: `? And `CITY_FILES := $(...)` should be included in the makefile code block, right?

Comment: thanks, it works. A minor problem is that every new run of make would also remove those `*.name` files, do you know the reason?

Comment: @user123: Hang on, I've been stupid, the `*.name` files are completely unneeded. I'll edit again, and remove them from the prereq list.

Comment: Hi, if you remove the `.name` files, the rule for `%.csv` would not be correct, and why do you still keep `$<`?

Comment: Sorry, I've been working in a noisy environment the last couple of days, making mistakes. What does the `write_data.py` script need in order to produce `newyork.csv`? Does it just need "newyork.name" as an argument, or must there be a file named "newyork.name" that contains something important?

Comment: No worries. Yes, it does need these name files to ensure only updating something with newly added cities. Actually, I have already worked this out. I think these .name files are indeed needed. Thanks!

Comment: @user123: So the files do actually contain something important? Their names are not the only important thing?

Comment: No, these files do not contain anything.

Comment: As I said in the question, this is just a way I thought of to update only new cities added in the list. I'm not sure if this is an appropriate way.